# send listview between pivoitems for desktop

Tags: c#, xaml, pivot

I'm doing a project, i have one pivot and this pivot have two pivotitem. The first one is called Lista and the second one is called Carrinho. In the first one i have a listview to store products and i have a binding to my productview model. When i select a button one the product he shows flyout and what i want is when i click the button that is on that flyout all the data that i have on the product will be send to the second pivotitem and i don't know how to do that mainly because the first pivotitem have the binding to productviewmodel and the second need to have the binding to other view model because the second pivotitem will be the order for the product and i think that maybe i just need to send the id of product because they are related in the database between this two tables (product and order),or just copy the data to the new ObservableCollection.

Here is the code that i have in xaml to better explain.

```
    <Pivot Grid.Column="1">

        <PivotItem Header="Lista">
            <ListView x:Name="List1" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ProdutoViewModel.Produtos}" Height="550" SelectionChanged="List1_SelectionChanged">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="list:Produto">
                        <ListView FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout="{StaticResource FlyoutBase1}" RightTapped="StackPanel_RightTapped">
                            <Button x:Name="CarrButton">
                                <Image Source="/Assets/cart.png" Height="20"/>
                                <Button.Flyout>
                                    <Flyout>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource BaseTextBlockStyle}">
                                                Adicionar este produto?
                                            </TextBlock>
                                            <Button Click="CarrConfirmation_Click">
                                                Carrinho
                                            </Button>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Flyout>
                                </Button.Flyout>
                            </Button>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Nome}" Margin="100,10,10,10"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Preco}" Margin="100,10,10,10"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Disponivel}" Margin="100,10,10,10"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Fornecedor}" Margin="100,10,10,10"/>
                                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Categoria}" Margin="100,10,10,10"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </ListView>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </PivotItem>
        <PivotItem Header="Carrinho">
            <ListView x:Name="Cart" ItemsSource="{Binding EncomendaViewModel.Encomendas}" Height="550">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="list:Produto">

                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="dasfas"></TextBlock>


                        </StackPanel>

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </PivotItem>

    </Pivot>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

The Messenger component of [MVVM Light](http://www.mvvmlight.net/) allows to pass data between classes of our app. Here is an example of how you could implement it. Don't forget to add the mvvmlight nuget package in your project.

```
// Sends a notification message with a Person as content in ProdutoViewModel.
var produto = new Produto { ProdutoName = "fuu", ProdutoPrice = 78 };
Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage<Produto>(produto, "event://FromProdutoViewModelToEncomendaViewModel"));

// Registers for incoming Notification messages EncomendaViewModel.
Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<Person>>(this, (message) =>
{ 
    // Checks the associated action.
    switch (message.Notification)
    {
        case "event://FromProdutoViewModelToEncomendaViewModel":
            // Gets the Person object
            var produto = message.Content as Produto;

            // Doing Stuff with the produto in EncomendaViewModel
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
});
```

Finally I will post [Marco Minerva's blog](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2014/06/25/how-to-send-string-and-content-messages-with-mvvm-light-messenger/) article who explained perfectly how it works.

**Solution 2**

Another solution is merging ProdutoViewModel and EncomendaViewModel in one ViewModel. This viewmodel will contain this two list which are binded on each Pivot.

Comment: I didn't understand your answer.
I will try to explain better, i have on a pivot data from a product data that can i add and it is save on database table products, what i want is when i press a button that is on flyout (which different product have is one) the information of that product will pass to the other pivot item, like i was doing the order of that product

Comment: You shoud read about Messenger and MVVM. You want to send objects between two ViewModels without navigation, for this the best way is the messenger.

Comment: Another solution is that you merge ProdutoViewModel and EncomendaViewModel in one. So you will have only one class to simplify your project. @Vitor

Comment: I would like to to this without adding packages.

Comment: I would like to to this without adding packages.
when i add one product to the first pivotitem i also add the product to the databse and that product have and id, there is any way that when i add the product to the second pivot i just can pass the id of that product and load all the information?

Comment: @Vitor, then you just need to work on the solution 2 on my answer.

Comment: In the first pivotitem i am doing the bind to products
ItemsSource="{x:Bind ProdutoViewModel.Produtos}
in the second pivotitem i think i need to bind to the order or if i want to show the product i bind the product again? 
all i want for now is when i press the button <Button Click="CarrConfirmation_Click"> to send me the information of that product to the order in the other pivotitem